# Error throw when assign right to user(s) to sharable folder "some or all identity references could not be translated"

Tags: c#, active-directory, windows-services, window, windows-console

I want to create a window service, which give user(s) rights to network folder means for one user it may be read option and for second write option or directory listing.

I am in testing phase, so created a console application. Its work for my local folder. But when I change the code and work for shareable network folder of my colleague and assign right to his local user like `Naveen\Bhavesh` (not global user like network service, local service, everyone etc), the above error throw.

I refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27719035/folder-permissions-some-or-all-identity-references-could-not-be-translated) which is same I want, but the solution not understandable. So can any body help to correct this code.

Also please not, I am working on LAN, not on active directory, but actually this is for client, who use active-directory and later implement this code there. So also give suggestion related to AD.

This is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.AccessControl;

namespace WindowUserRights
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //The below commented code is related to my pc and its working fine as I want.
            //// Specify the directory you want to manipulate.
            //string path = @"D:\\Project\\E\\Exercise\\WindowUserRights\\MyDir";

            //string user1Read = "AJAYENDRA\\ASPNET";
            //string user2Write = "AJAYENDRA\\Guest";
            //string user3Write = "AJAYENDRA\\ReportUser";

           //The below code is related to a shared folder of network pc and its gives the error when access the user. 
           // Specify the directory you want to manipulate.
            string path = @"\\NAVEEN\Jobs";

            string user1Read = "NAVEEN\\Bhavesh";
            string user2Write = "NAVEEN\\Guest";

            try
            {
                //string DirectoryName = path + "TestDirectory";                
                string DirectoryName = "";

                DirectoryName = CheckAndCreateDirectory(path + "\\JobNo_user1Read_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff"));  //check directory and create if does not exist;

                // Add the access control entry to the directory.
                Console.WriteLine("Adding access control entry for " + DirectoryName + " to user :- " + user1Read);
                AddDirectorySecurity(DirectoryName, user1Read, FileSystemRights.Modify, AccessControlType.Allow);

                DirectoryName = CheckAndCreateDirectory(path + "\\JobNo_user2Write_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff"));  //check directory and create if does not exist;
                Console.WriteLine("Adding access control entry for " + DirectoryName + " to user :- " + user2Write);
                AddDirectorySecurity(DirectoryName, user2Write, FileSystemRights.ListDirectory, AccessControlType.Allow);

                Console.WriteLine("Done.");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        //Check and create a directory, if does not exist.
        public static string CheckAndCreateDirectory(string path)
        {
            // Specify the directory you want to manipulate.
            //string path = @"D:\\Project\\E\\Exercise\\WindowUserRights\\MyDir";

            try
            {
                // Determine whether the directory exists.
                if (Directory.Exists(path))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("That path exists already.");
                    return "";
                }

                // Try to create the directory.
                DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                Console.WriteLine("The directory was created successfully at {0}.", Directory.GetCreationTime(path));


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
                throw e;
            }
            //finally { }
            return path;
        }

        // Adds an ACL entry on the specified directory for the specified account.
        public static void AddDirectorySecurity(string FileName, string Account, FileSystemRights Rights, AccessControlType ControlType)
        {
            // Create a new DirectoryInfo object.
            DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(FileName);

            // Get a DirectorySecurity object that represents the 
            // current security settings.
            DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();

            //the below line throw the error "some or all identity references could not be translated"
            // Add the FileSystemAccessRule to the security settings. 
            dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(Account,
                                                            Rights,
                                                            ControlType)); 

            // Set the new access settings.
            dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);

        }


    }
}
```